# Identify kids fantasy anthology series circa 1995

Tags: story-identification, tv

Please could you help identify a children's TV show that aired on UK terrestrial television (not satellite) perhaps some time between 1992 and 1998?

Details :

- Anthology series, not a serial
- Stories were creepy, scary, fantasy in nature - like a Twilight Zone style show but for kids
- Can remember episodes about a toy soldier and a rocking chair (possibly a flashback), and one with a whirlpool.

Sorry if details are a bit scant, this is all that is remembered from a very young age. Some details might even be remembered incorrectly so near-matches appreciated.

Comment: Do you remember if the toy soldier was an antagonist? And by it not being a serial, the stories were unconnected, so this isn't like *Eerie Indiana* or *Around the Twist*, but more like *Are You Afraid of the Dark*?

Comment: Do you remember whether the characters spoke in a UK accent/dialect (and if so, which one) or if it was more of a US accent?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots thanks for response - it's my wife's memory, she doesn't recall a lot. I've edited the post as she thinks the toy soldier and rocking chair were part of the same imagery, possibly a flashback in a haunted house? Format of 'Afraid of the Dark' seems right but don't think that was distributed in the UK.

Comment: Remake was released in the UK in 2019 according to IMDB. No mention from the original series of a UK distribution, but they do mention it was known as "Are You Afraid of the Dark?" there. https://moirasafraidofthedark.wordpress.com/2017/04/14/are-you-afraid-of-the-dark-season-2-episode-8-the-tale-of-the-frozen-ghost/ mentions a rocking chair. :-P Also https://areyouafraidofthedark.fandom.com/wiki/The_Tale_of_the_Whispering_Walls

Comment: @FuzzyBoots We've watched that episode and she's pretty sure that's not the show. We *think* it is something British, probably shown on Children's ITV (BBC less likely to produce or show this kind of stuff). It's a shame because 'Are You Afraid of the Dark' definitely fits the description and the right time frame.

Comment: It seems "Are You Afraid of the Dark" did air on Children's ITV (it's mentioned on the box of the 2007 DVD release of the 1992 seasons: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Are-You-Afraid-Dark-Complete/dp/B000M5KTRM/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1316187433&sr=8-1 ). Goosebumps, a similar anthology series, aired on CBBC.

Comment: I'm British, and I can confirm that *Are You Afraid of the Dark* definitely was on either CITV or CBBC in the 90s - because I remember seeing some of [this episode](https://areyouafraidofthedark.fandom.com/wiki/The_Tale_of_Apartment_214). If I had to take a guess, I would say CITV was more likely.

Comment: Don't know about a whirlpool, but [this episode](https://areyouafraidofthedark.fandom.com/wiki/The_Tale_of_the_Forever_Game) had someone sinking in quicksand.

Comment: I wonder if it could have been an episode of the *Goosebumps* TV series? Goosebumps was REALLY popular in the UK in the 90s, and I know the TV series was shown on UK TV (couldn't say whether ITV or BBC though.)

Comment: Another possibility - [Deadtime Stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadtime_Stories_(TV_series)). One episode did have some toy soldiers, and I'm told it was shown in the UK, though I have no memory of ever seeing it.